# Rules of thumb for when to use a site, a subsite, or a site collection?

Tags: architecture, site-collection, publishing-site

I am developing a company website/portal in SharePoint, and am trying to figure
out the best way to organise it into site collections, sites and subsites --
I'm confused by the terminology I think.

The site has a public-facing Internet presence which is to be managed via the
Publishing WCM features of SharePoint.  Behind the scenes there will be some
portal features, such as personalised dashboards and a collaborative wiki.

For the public-facing content, the site structure is as so:

- Home
- Company

  - About Us
  - Testimonials
  - ...
  - ...
  - etc
- Products

  - Product 1
  - Product 2
  - ...
  - ...
  - etc
- Support

  - a support section for customers requiring a login
- Contact Us

  - one web page with contact details

The top-level sections in my hierarchy, i.e. Home, Company, Products, Support, Contact Us would share the same master page and top-level navigation, and Company and Products will each have a left-placed submenu to go to each page in their section.  I'm wondering how to structure this in terms of sites/subsites/site collections.

My initial thoughts is to have a site collection where the top-level site for
the collection is the public-facing publishing side of things.

But then I'm not sure whether 'Company' and 'Products' should be subsites of the 
top-level publishing site, or simply pages within the top-level publishing site.
As Company and Products are just collections of basic HTML content, to have each one as a 'subsite' feels like overkill, but that may just be because I'm
not used to the terminology.  I would ordinarily just think of them as subsections of a website.

The 'Support' section is essentially a set of embedded mini-applications such
as issue tracking.  As it is more substantial, and is not viewable by anonymous users, it feels like it would warrant being at least a subsite, or maybe it should be a separate site collection?

I would guess that the 'behind-the-scenes' portal, only accessible by employees, with features such as dashboards/collaborative wiki, would again be in a separate site collection.

I guess my general question is, **what are the rules of thumb for when to use a site, when to use a subsite, and when to use a site collection**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post [When to use a Site Collection over a Sub-Site](http://joeshepherd.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!9AE2097A4A610B63!294.entry) by Joe Shepherd helped me a lot when I had similar questions.

Comment: the above link is broken - Error message: 'This Windows Live Space is no longer available.'

Answer (score 1):

A more authoritative source for site planning is from Microsoft itself - [Plan sites and site collections (SharePoint 2010).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288638.aspx) The approach calls for a thorough requirement analysis in the planning (see the Site Planning data worksheet in the link above).

It's not clear from above question what version/edition is being used. There is also a reference for SharePoint Server 2010 -
[Plan for sites and solutions (SharePoint Server 2010).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789336%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

I am presuming above that links from Microsoft do not readily disappear & are updated as required.

Answer (score 0):

This similar [post](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1048) helped me:

> **Some of the reasons that I might pick a Site Collection**
>
> - I have a branded new site and I want it created with no relation to any other site. If you are creating a new site and it's not related to
>     any other sites that you have in your existing site hierarchy or
>     SharePoint farm then you chose a site collection.
> - If you require a dedicated URL to your site. You want your client to access and upload documents so you want to create a URL for your
>     partner at http://partner.mycompany.com . You can bind this URL to a
>     site collection. This URL cannot be bound to a sub site of an existing
>     site collection.
> - You want to create a managed path called divisions and you want to create a site for each division you your organization. Each division
>     wants complete control over their site and sub sites and want to be
>     found at URL divisions/divisionName.
> - Where you require to have a quota set on a site created you will need to use a site collection as only site collections can have quotas
>     assigned to them.
> - If you need a dedicated Content Database for your site as you expect to have vast amounts of data and documents and you require it
>     to be more secure that normal, you can can configure a dedicated site
>     collection with a dedicated content database attached to it.
> - If you were purchasing hosted environments from a hosting provider then you would also see the difference in a site collection and a sub
>     site in the cost model offered by the hosting company. You will notice
>     that getting a site collection provisioned with have a higher admin
>     cost than just creating a sub site. Sub site creation can be carried
>     out by a member of the owners group of any site or site collection.
>     Whereas site collection creation has to be completed by Farm
>     Administrators unless there is a mechanism provided though web
>     wizards.
> - As part of a backup and recovery policy you want your data to be very quickly restored if there are any problems or if there has been
>     content that has gotten deleted that you need to retrieve. A site
>     collection is better in this case because you can restore the site
>     collection more easily than you can restore a site or a sub site of a
>     site.
>
> **Some of the reasons why you should select a sub site:**
>
> - You want to inherit the same security for the new sub site as its parent site & the security model for your organization already exists.
>     You want to create a new site but you don't want to change or move
>     away from the existing security model implemented already.
> - There has been a team in your organization unit that created many new site columns and site content types that you would like to use
>     throughout your site and its sub sites -- as parent sites can contain
>     site content types, these can be used in all subs sites of the site
>     hierarchy -- Site Collections break this functionality.
> - You want to allow the Site Owners and Designers to manage all sites that get created without any overhead of having to log a support call
>     for a new site collection.
> - You want to aggregate data throughout your site hierarchy using Web Parts like the Content Query Web Part, Data View Web Part and other
>     data aggregation Web Parts.
> - You have a site template that you want to apply to the new site that creates a couple of lists and libraries as part of the template
>     -- an example may be you want a Tasks Manager Site Template where a site can maintain and manage all your tasks using tasks lists and to
>     have them integrate with Outlook.
> - If your site is going to be a short lived site and it's only going to be used in the process of creating some other content. An example
>     might be a meeting site where you create a site that is created from a
>     Meetings Templates. You can record and schedule meetings regarding the
>     production of a catalog of products for your organization. This site
>     is short lived and won't be in existence after the production of the
>     catalog is completed.

Comment: Please explain the solution. It's great to provide a link, but as you can see links break over time, rendering answers without further explanation meaningless. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I posted a new answer (see my post above).

Comment: Sorry for my poor answer. I just wanted to help providing a similar link than the previous one. In the post I shared, there is a discussion about "When should we use a Site Collection and when should we use a Sub Site?". I thought that it could be useful for site planning.